# Copying Billing to Shipping Address text input arrays

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm wondering how I can get input value when its name is an array.

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>Address 1:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="billing_info[]" /></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td>Address 2:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="billing_info[]" /></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td>City:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="billing_info[]" /></td>
    <td>State:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="billing_info[]" /></td>
</tr>   

    <th><p>Shipping Info</p></th>

<tr>
       <td colspan="2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="shipping_address" 
             name="shipping_checkbox" />Same as Billing Address </td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td>Address 1:</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="shipping_info[]" /></td>
```

Seems like there is a lot of example for copying input values using jQuery, but how can I get values from `billing_info[]` and copy them over to `shipping_info[]`?

Comment: Just a note that you probably don't want to use unconstrained values in the state area.  New York, new York, new york, newyork, new  york, etc, are the kinds of values that you'll get.  Use a dropdown instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through each, using the iterator `i` to choose which shipping input to update:

```
$('#copy').click(function(){
    $('input[name="billing[]"]').each(function(i, el){
        $('input[name="shipping[]"]').eq(i).val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

(my code assumes you're tying this action into the click of a button)

Comment: Thank you Adam, this is great. Time to look into iterator more.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the same number of shipping elements and billing elements And that they have corresponding positions in your html, this should work.

```
var shipping = $("input[name='shipping_info[]']");
var billing = $("input[name='billing_info[]']");
shipping.each(function(i, o) {
  $(billing.get(i)).val($(o).val());
})
```

**See working demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FJjvt/**

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    var value = '';
    $('input[name="billing_info[]"]').each(function() {
        value += this.value;
    });
    $('input[name="shipping_info[]"]').val(value);
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/trmr9/1/

Comment: Thank you Nicola. But this function actually combines all the values into one 'value' variable.

Comment: sorry i understood that was what you needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs need to have unique id's. Then you can use JQuery like this:

```
$('#shippingaddress1').val($('#billingAddress1').val());
```

for each pair of inputs